# Liferay 6.0.5 - Including common javascript at the end of all portlets, before scripts?

Tags: javascript, performance, liferay

I'd like to load all my javascript at the bottom of each page, but in liferay, I'm limited to `<header-portlet-javascript>`, which places the javascript in the header.

If I include the JS manually at the bottom of each relevant JSP, I wind up duplicating a number of `<script>` includes.

What's the best way to achieve what I need? I have a number of portlets that all require the same set of javascript libraries, some of which are large, and I'm targetting mobile devices, so every byte counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get access to how the whole page of HTML is generated in your theme, in templates/portal-normal.vm. Change this to adjust to your requirements.